# How are Dynamic Data Sites done in 2016?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I'm looking into creating a site that is driven by data/templates in the database.
An example of an template could be like this https://www.mc.vanderbilt.edu/victr/dcc/redcap/demos/redcap_v6.5.20/Design/data_dictionary_codebook.php?pid=1

I've found an ASP.NET solution called [Dynamic Data Web Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx), however it's very old and seems dead :(

I realize this is opinionated, but I can't find any "modern" ASP.NET framework that solves this "data driven views" problem. How is this solved today?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a link to an article posted on 10/2/2013 that maybe helpful (or not). http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/946/data-driven-custom-view-engine-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Thanks. I did find that one. The problem with that one is that it's "reinventing" the wheel - sort of. Dynamic Data Sites exists and solves that exact issue. I don't believe that these kind of sites totally disappeared. They must have evolved into something else, and that something else I cannot find